# Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio - cant select 'Other data source' when adding New Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, db2, linked-server

I am running SQL Server 2017 Express (64-bit) on a remote Linux machine. On my Windows 10 box, I have installed the latest version of Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. I have successfully connected it to my SQL Server (on my Linux box).

I now want to add a linked server, specifically to a DB2 database running on an IBM i server. Unfortunately when I got to add the Linked Server, the option to select 'Other data source' as the Server type (it is the only other option, below 'SQL Server') is grayed out and cannot be selected. All the documentation/posts I've read online make no reference to this happening and it seems like I should be able to simply select the option.

I suppose it's possible that I don't have an OLE DB provider for DB2 (though I believe that I do), but even then, you'd think that I could at least select the option and then "try" to open the drop-box to specify a provider.

Anyone have any ideas as to why this behavior is occurring and what I could do to fix it?

Comment: As of SQL Server 2019, linked servers to platforms other than SQL Server are not supported on SQL Server for Linux.  See "Unsupported Features & Services" here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-editions-and-components-2019?view=sql-server-linux-2017

Comment: This is useful information - thank you, but it turns out that I am actually running SQL Server 2017 on Linux - should this work on that version? (I will edit my original question to amend this mistake)

Comment: Sorry, when I said "As of SQL Server 2019" that was intended to include all prior versions...  My bad, that wasn't so clear.  Here's the article for SQL Server 2017 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-editions-and-components-2017?view=sql-server-linux-2017

Comment: I see, so no previous version of SQL Server on Linux as of this point has supported linked servers, unless they're SQL Servers? So in this case, if I want to move forward, I'll have to set up the SQL Server on a different platform.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.